# Datadog APM is not creating through terraform

Tags: terraform, datadog, apm

Is there a way to create a Datadog APM page via terraform

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5HZV.png)

I do have a file which creates datadog logs

It does create a datadog logs, but can't create the APM page.
Do I need to add anything else to my code?

Thank you!

And this is my terraform code:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "datadog" {
  family = "datadog-${var.env}"
  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      "name" : "datadog-agent",
      "image" : "public.ecr.aws/datadog/agent:latest",
      "cpu" : 100,
      "memory" : 512,
      "essential" : true,
      "mountPoints" : [
        {
          "containerPath" : "/var/run/docker.sock",
          "sourceVolume" : "docker_sock",
          "readOnly" : null
        },
        {
          "containerPath" : "/host/sys/fs/cgroup",
          "sourceVolume" : "cgroup",
          "readOnly" : null
        },
        {
          "containerPath" : "/host/proc",
          "sourceVolume" : "proc",
          "readOnly" : null
        }
      ],
      "environment" : [
        {
          "name" : "DD_API_KEY",
          "value" : local.op_secrets["dd_api_key"]
        },
        {
          "name" : "DD_SITE",
          "value" : "datadoghq.com"
        },
        {
          "name" : "DD_LOGS_ENABLED",
          "value" : "true"
        },
        {
          "name" : "DD_LOGS_CONFIG_CONTAINER_COLLECT_ALL",
          "value" : "true"
        },
        {
          "name" : "DD_PROCESS_AGENT_ENABLED",
          "value" : "true"
        },
        {
          "name" : "DD_ECS_COLLECT_RESOURCE_TAGS_EC2",
          "value" : "true"
        },
        {
          "name" : "DD_APM_ENABLED",
          "value" : "true"
        },
        {
          "name" : "DD_APM_NON_LOCAL_TRAFFIC",
          "value" : "true"
        },
        {
          "name" : "DD_LOGS_INJECTION",
          "value" : "true"
        },
        {
          "name" : "DD_TRACE_AGENT_PORT",
          "value" : "8126"
        }

      ]
      "family" : "datadog-agent-task"
    }

  ])
  volume {
    name      = "docker_sock"
    host_path = "/var/run/docker.sock"
  }
  volume {
    name      = "proc"
    host_path = "/proc/"
  }
  volume {
    name      = "cgroup"
    host_path = "/sys/fs/cgroup/"
  }
}
```

As you see, I have "DD_APM_ENABLED" as 'true', but still cant get datadog APM page to work.

Please help!

Comment: Really would appreciate any help

Comment: Have you instrumented any apps or services in your ECS containers to use APM? It's not something that gets generated by default like logs, you need to configure the specific code that you want to connect to APM. https://docs.datadoghq.com/containers/amazon_ecs/apm/

Comment: Thank you for your responce. I did follow that link when I was creating datadog task definition I added this part to it:
{
    "name": "DD_APM_ENABLED",
    "value": "true"
  },
  {
    "name": "DD_APM_NON_LOCAL_TRAFFIC",
    "value": "true"
  }

So lost